# Why is firestore not allowing access for array check security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to have a list of things like such

`clients/{clientId}/points/{pointId}`

and the fields at this document would be something like

```
point aaaa = { device: '1234', messages: 2, color: 'red'... },
point bbbb = { device: 'AAAA', messages: 2, color: 'red'... },
```

a user has in the token the clientId and an array of devices

```
{
    uid: 'abc',
    token: {
        clientId: 'test1',
        devices: ['1234']
    }
}
```

and my security rules look like this.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /clients/{clientId} {
      match /visible/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.token.clientId == clientId
      }
      match /points/{$pointId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.token.clientId == clientId && resource.data.device in request.auth.token.devices;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So if I get point aaa directly it will work but if i want to get all points such as

`firestore.ref('path/to/points').where('color', '=', 'red')`

I get access denied.

So how do i get all of the points which i'm allowed to see (which will be in the thousands).

Comment: Are you certain that custom claims can contain list values?  I can find no information that confirms or denies this.

Comment: when I log it from the front end it is an array value. Also the simulator supports entering an array of strings.

Comment: i've also tried storing the list in a different path and doing ```resource.data.device in get(/documents/.../path/to/user/devices)``` and it works the same way as the method posted for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that **security rules are not filters**.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules):

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security
>   rules are not filters — queries are all or nothing. To save you time and
>   resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential
>   result set instead of the actual field values for all of your
>   documents. If a query could potentially return documents that the
>   client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.

So, if your entire query may fail to read some document in the result set, the entire query fails.  It sounds like your query is not exclusively returning documents that the user may read with their custom claims.

Comment: this was very helpful thank you. If i expand my query like so ```queries = devices.map(did => query.where('device', '==', did)) and then combine results I can get my expected behavior

Comment: If you edit your answer to explain multi query and combine results I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @matthewdaniel That is well beyond the scope of your question.  Please ask another question if you have followup concerns.